# Web application and web service as a client of another web service

Tags: web-services, rest

If I use a standalone application to interact with a Restful web service I use Apache HttpClient or its Fluent API.
How do I interact with a web service using a web application or from another Restful web service?
Do I again go back to Apache HttpClient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web service client is a web service client, no matter if who's doing the  consuming is a standalone application, a web application or even another web service. You could consume them how you see fit:

- use a JAX-RS aware client like the [RESTEasy client framework](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html) (I see from your profile you are using JAX-RS);
- use a (generic) REST aware client like [Resty](http://beders.github.io/Resty/Resty/Overview.html);
- use [Apache HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/);
- heck, you could even use [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) :)